# Installing XML in R in a conda environment with python 3.6 fails on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, r, xml, anaconda, conda

Ultimately I am trying to install package DESeq2 in R but it fails because the package XML will not install.This is how to recreate the problem:

```
#Create a conda environment with python 3.6 (from Anaconda). 

conda create -n py36_test python=3.6

#Activate the new environment

conda activate py36_test

#Install R 4.0.2 from conda-forge

conda install -c conda-forge r-base=4.0.2

Start R

> install.packages('XML')
.....
....
checking for pkg-config... no
checking for xml2-config... /mnt/data/miniconda_python3/miniconda3/envs/py36_test/bin/xml2-config
USE_XML2 = yes
SED_EXTENDED_ARG: -E
Minor 9, Patch 10 for 2.9.10
Located parser file -I/mnt/data/miniconda_python3/miniconda3/envs/py36_test/include/libxml2 -I/mnt/data/miniconda_python3/miniconda3/envs/py36_test/include/parser.h
Checking for 1.8:  -I/mnt/data/miniconda_python3/miniconda3/envs/py36_test/include/libxml2 -I/mnt/data/miniconda_python3/miniconda3/envs/py36_test/include
Using libxml2.*
checking for gzopen in -lz... yes
checking for xmlParseFile in -lxml2... no
checking for xmlParseFile in -lxml... no
configure: error: "libxml not found"
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'XML'
 removing '/mnt/data/miniconda_python3/miniconda3/envs/py36_test/lib/R/library/XML'

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/RtmphXKzlB/downloaded_packages'
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("XML") :
  installation of package 'XML' had non-zero exit status
```

I have tried various solutions which have worked for others with the same problem but these do not work in my case, such as
`apt install libxml2-dev  libcurl4-openssl-dev`.
I'm actually not sure what these two lines mean in the output:

```
checking for xmlParseFile in -lxml2... no

checking for xmlParseFile in -lxml... no
```

What exactly is it looking for?

Is there any way to increase debug level when investigating an R installation issue?

Can someone explain how I could compile XML and install it in R ?